# Swift Socket, listening to incoming message

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, swift4

I am trying to implement swift socket in my application. I am pretty new to socket programming. I was able to send messages through the socket. But I am unable to listen to any messages from server. I have implemented the following code:

```
    let host = Urls.GetServerIP()
    let port = portNo
    client = TCPClient(address: host, port: Int32(port))

    switch client?.connect(timeout: 10) {
    case .success?:
        print((readResponse(from: client!)))
    case .failure(let error)?:
        print( String(describing: error))
        break

    case .none: break

    }
```

In the above code, I am able to read an incoming message which comes as soon as I connect. But, I am unable to find a way to know that there is a message from the server, after couple of minutes.

Are there any specific call backs to know when a new message arrives from the server?

I have implemented StreamDelegate to my class. But no call backs are being triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your code lacks continuous reading, which is the reason that you only get a message once. I used to use SwiftSocket myself some time ago. The problem with this framework is that it is too simple and lacks a lot of functionality, for example encryption.

I switched to [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), which is the Swiss army knife to handle socket connections in Swift.

Here is a short Example:

```
import CocoaAsyncSocket

class TcpSocketConnection: GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {

    let tcpSocket: GCDAsyncSocket?

    init(host: String, port: UInt16) {
        self.tcpSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self)
        do {
            try tcpSocket?.connect(toHost: host, onPort: port, withTimeout: 5.0)
        } catch let error {
            print("Cannot open socket to \(host):\(port): \(error)")
            self.tcpSocket = nil
        }
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port: UInt16) {
        self.tcpSocket?.readData(toLength: 1024, withTimeout: 60.0)
    }

    func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {
        // Process data
        self.tcpSocket?.readData(toLength: 1024, withTimeout: 60.0, tag: 0)
    }

}
```

The code highly depends from how your server behaves and what you exactly want to do. Socket handling is not an easy task, especially when you add encryption (which you should do in modern applications). You can use the [documentation](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/wiki/Intro_GCDAsyncSocket) as a starting point but you will have to read and learn a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. One question though, you have written the code to read the data every time the didRead method i called. Is it necessary? I mean, cant the framework the incoming message on its own, whenever it receives the same from the server or do i need to write the readData in every delegate?

Comment: As far as I know you need to do reading and buffering by yourself. But if there is a possibility for automatic receiving, I am very interested :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can use **SocketIOClient** for web sockets. It can be used to send or receive messages through sockets.

Link:

```
 https://github.com/nuclearace/Socket.IO-Client-Swift
```

Comment: I am not using websocket. The port is different. And socket.io is not implemented on the server side. So for normal socket programming, can i use socket.io?

Comment: Yes you can use you just need to include the ticket url and port at which socket is connected.

Comment: @RahulDasgupta, [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and [Network Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) are different things altogether. They even work on different OSI levels.

Comment: But I think **SocketIOClient** can be used to connect any sockets.